# transforming math expression from text into calculated one

Tags: javascript, jquery

inside certain calculation I'm generating an math expression in javascript like

```
var myExpression = '';
if (!isNaN(myVal) && myVal> 0) {
    myExpression += '(' + myVal+ ' * ' + someVal + ') +';                    
}
```

and based on certain user events I'm getting generated expression in console.log as you expect

```
(1 * 1) + (10 * 5) + ...
```

or

```
(10 * 5) + ...
```

How can I transform this math expression representation into real expression and to store it's result into variable?

Comment: Why not use eval() in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval()` on the string, which will run it as JavaScript. This will allow the math expression to be computed:

```
eval(myExpression);
```

Just note be wary of using `eval()`. See [Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea). Although that being said there are many things people can now do with the JavaScript built-in console, as users can execute any JavaScript they wish on any web page. See the [third comment by of this answer byPrestaul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/86580/3149020) on potential problems this can have. If you ensure that the variables cannot be directly manipulated by the user then your fine.

Comment: this is the bad solution.

Comment: because i can pass some script into variables from the client side to execute it on a server. Also this is the bad habit to use _eval_ function

Comment: @The The user can do that with or without `eval()`. Browsers have a JavaScript console built-in now a days, they can do that despite having `eval()` in the code.

Comment: The _eval_ function open up your code for XSS attacks, this is not only my point. [link](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [math.js](http://mathjs.org), which comes with it's own expression parser:

```
math.eval('(1 * 1) + (10 * 5)');  // 51
```

or provide variables in a scope and use them in the expression:

```
math.eval('(myVal * someVal)', {myVal: 2, someVal: 10});  // 20
```

you can also parse an expression into a tree and do operations on the tree, see docs:

http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html
http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/expression_trees.html